# Perl one-liner that works on multiple lines?

Tags: perl

I have a file that contains pairs of lines that look like this:

```
 FIRST PIECE OF INFO
 PIECE 2 | PIECE 3 | PIECE 4 | ...
```

I need to output this:

```
FIRST PIECE OF INFO\tPIECE 2\tPIECE 3 ...
```

An I also need to do some more regexp magic on the lines themselves.

Can this be done using a perl one-liner? My problem here is that using -p will handle the file one line at a time, whereas I need to deal with two lines at a time. My solution was first running another one-liner that removes all linebreaks from the file (I had another separator between different pairs of lines) but this seems too cumbersome and I'm sure there's a better way.

Comment: Why do you insist on a one-line Perl program?

Comment: I do not insist - in the end I did it with more than one line. However, it is my experience that in Perl one liners have an amazing power and so maybe I'm just missing something basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the simple solution is to turn all the newlines and pipes into tabs. It sounds a bit crazy, but at first glance, it does sound like what you want:

```
perl -pwe 'tr/\n|/\t\t/' yourfile.txt
```

But there is something that does not match up with your problem description. You say:

> *I have a file that contains pairs of **lines***

Which would mean that your file *actually* looks something like this:

```
FIRST PIECE OF INFO
PIECE 2 | PIECE 3 | PIECE 4 | ...
SECOND PIECE OF INFO
PIECE 2a | PIECE 3b | PIECE 4b | ...
THIRD... etc
```

In which case blindly transliterating the newlines would put everything on a single line. Now, my interpretation of this is that what you want is something like this (with tabs and newlines denoted literally):

```
FIRST PIECE OF INFO\tPIECE 2\tPIECE 3\tPIECE 4 | ...\n
SECOND PIECE OF INFO\tPIECE 2a\tPIECE 3b\tPIECE 4b | ...\n
```

This is not achieved with a simple transliteration.

```
perl -plwe 'next if !/\S/; $_ = join "\t", $_, split /\s*\|\s*/,<>;' file.txt
```

Note: The `next if !/\S/;` statement is only to prevent the stream from being paused at the end in case the file contains an odd number of lines. If it does, the file handle `<>` will try to read from STDIN, and you will need to press `Ctrl-D` to manually stop it.

The [`Data::Dumper`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data%3a%3aDumper) output looks like this, with `$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1` showing whitespace characters:

```
$VAR1 = "FIRST PIECE OF INFO\tPIECE 2\tPIECE 3\tPIECE 4\t...\n";
$VAR1 = "SECOND PIECE OF INFO\tPIECE 2a\tPIECE 3b\tPIECE 4b\t...\n";
```

The one-liner for the above output looks like this, somewhat rewritten:

```
perl -MData::Dumper -nlwe '
    $Data::Dumper::Useqq=1; 
    next if !/\S/; 
    $_ = join "\t", $_, split /\s*\|\s*/,<>; 
    print Dumper $_;' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you with the `more regexp magic` without knowing what it is, but this will combine the lines as your describe

```
perl -lne 'print join "\t", $_, split /\|/, <ARGV>' myfile
```

Comment: "More regexp magic" simply means that I do additional changes to the lines.

Comment: I realise that, but I can't integrate those changes into my solution without understanding what they are.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach:

```
perl -pe'$"="\t";chomp;$_="@{[$_,split q(\|),<>]}"'
```